# Org-mode: Translate Latex Abstract keyword

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I am Brazilian and constantly writing papers for university. I am now using this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127715/how-to-place-abstract-before-first-section-in-org-modes-latex-export) to place a cool block containing the abstract description of the paper per se. But in portuguese abstract is called resumo, and I am supposed to write both of them, portuguese and english version in every single paper. Pretty much like this

[image]

How can I make emacs help me out here? Is there a config for this or should I mess with elisp?

Comment: @Nick: the image worked on Firefox 55.0.2 on Linux

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
#+language: en,pt
#+latex_compiler: xelatex
#+latex_header: \usepackage[AUTO]{polyglossia}
#+begin_english
#+begin_abstract
Abstract
#+end_abstract
#+end_english

#+begin_abstract
Resumo
#+end_abstract
```

or this, if you prefer babel

```
#+language: pt
#+latex_header: \usepackage[english,AUTO]{babel}
#+macro: lang @@latex:\selectlanguage{$1}@@
{{{lang(english)}}}
#+begin_abstract
Abstract
#+end_abstract
{{{lang(portuguese)}}}
#+begin_abstract
Resumo
#+end_abstract
```

Comment: xelatex compiles with errors! babel compiles fine but the keyword does not get translated.  see this http://imgur.com/a/OWGBL

Comment: If xelatex doesn't work you might have a older version of Org or you might be missing some LaTeX packages. There was a typo in *portuguese* the answer in the sample which I corrected.

Comment: I have seen the typo. No luck so far.I have installed elatex from apt. What tex dependencies should I get?  I um running the latest org-plus from melpa